# Null Cell from VBA Formula if Negative

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, excel-formula, null

I have a formula that sums the difference between two dates, however, some rows do not yet have a second date. The excel value defaults these cells to numerical values of "-44,000+". I'm trying to build an IF(SUM statement that would test if the value is negative, and if so, then that cell is nulled. Any advice or alternative suggestions are appreciated!

```
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim sFormula As String
    Dim formatcells As ListColumn
    
    Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")

    sFormula = "=sum(([@[Closed]])-([@[Created]]))"
    
    tbl.ListColumns("Days Open").DataBodyRange.Cells(1).Formula = sFormula

    Set formatcells = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns("Days Open")
    formatcells.Range.NumberFormat = "0"
```

Comment: 1. You do not need the SUM() wrapper: `sFormula = "=[@[Closed]]-([@[Created]"` 2. just use a number format of `"0;;;` but that will "hide" the negative not make it an empty string.  IF you want and empty string the: `sFormula = "=IF([@[Closed]]-([@[Created]<0,"""",[@[Closed]]-([@[Created])"`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the guidance, Scott! I tried your suggested formula but kept getting the 1004 error code, however, after some additional parenthesis adjustments, it works!

sFormula = "=IF(([@[Closed]])-([@[Created]])<0,"""",(([@[Closed]])-([@[Created]])))